# How to draw \hline which does not cross a cell gotten by merged ones?

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabularray, nicematrix, tabulary

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } \hline
        col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{4em}{Multiple row} & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
        & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
        & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This code gives

[image]

How can I make \hline cross only two last columns ?

Comment: I think this is the purpose of cline.  Have you come across that?  https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables#Reference_guide

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned @Teepeemm in his comment, instead of `\hline`s you should use `\cline{2-3}`. Or instead of `tabular` table use `tblr` of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } \hline
        col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{4em}{Multiple row} 
        & cell2 & cell3 \\ \cline{2-3}
        & cell5 & cell6 \\ \cline{2-3}
        & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

or with \verb+tblr+

    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines, vlines,
        colspec = { Q[c, wd=4em] c c c }
    }  
        col1 & col2 & col3          \\ 
    \SetCell[r=3]{l} Multiple row      % tabularray syntax for multirow cell
        & cell2 & cell3             \\
        & cell5 & cell6             \\  
        & cell8 & cell9             \\  
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines] 
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
    \Block{3-1}{Multiple row} 
    & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
    & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
    & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Using `multirow` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{col1}    & col2  & col3  \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Multiple row} & cell2 & cell3 \\ \cline{2-3} 
                              & cell5 & cell6 \\ \cline{2-3} 
                              & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My heartiest congratulations on recently passing the 50k reputation mark!

Comment: @Mico I thank you infinitely from the bottom of my heart. You are special.